# sed read entire lines from one file and replace lines in another file

Tags: sed, replace

I have two files: file1, file with content as follows:

file1:

```
f1 line1
f1 line2
f1 line3
```

file2:

```
f2 line1
f2 line2
f2 line3
f2 line4
```

Wonder how I can use sed to read line 1 to line 3 from file1 and use these lines to replace line2 to line 3 in file 2.

The output should be like this:

```
f2 line1
f1 line1
f1 line2
f1 line3
f2 line4
```

Can any one help? Thanks,

Comment: Sed is not the right tool for this job. You can do it, but it is like driving a nail with a knife.

Comment: do you have any better suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Yes, awk would be a vastly better choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have GNU sed which supports `s///e`, you can use the `e` to call `head -n3 file1`

I think (w/o yet testing):

`sed '2d;3s/.*/head -n3 file1/e' file2`

I'll go verify...

Comment: thanks. this works. but can you please explain a bit about the use of "s///e" in this case?

Comment: the 'e' is executing the contents of the pattern buffer in the shell... so `s/.*/echo test/e` would delete the entire line, shell out the `echo test` command and then insert the stdout from `echo test` in the output.  So, `s/.*/echo test/e` is equivalent to `d;a test` ...  the stdout doesn't come back into the pattern buffer.

Comment: May also be equivalent to `d; e echo test` ... `e` not necessarily part of `s///e`.  It just tends to be more flexible than bare `e`

Answer (score 0):

sed is the best tool for doing `s/old/new` on individual strings. That's not what you're trying to do so you shouldn't be considering trying to use sed for it. Using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    if ( FNR <= num ) {
        new = new $0 ORS
    }
    next
}
(beg <= FNR) && (FNR <= end) {
    if ( !done++ ) {
        printf "%s", new
    }
    next
}
{ print }
```

.

```
$ awk -v num=3 -v beg=2 -v end=3 -f tst.awk file1 file2
f2 line1
f1 line1
f1 line2
f1 line3
f2 line4
```

To read a different number of lines from file1 just change the value of `num`, to use the replacement text for a different range of lines in file2 just change the values of `beg` and `end`. So, for example, if you wanted to use 10 lines of data from a pipe (e.g. `seq 15 |`) instead of file1 and wanted to replace between lines 3 and 17 of a file2 like you have but with 20 lines instead of 4 then you'd leave the awk script as-is and just tweak how you call it:

```
$ seq 15 | awk -v num=10 -v beg=3 -v end=17 -f tst.awk - file2
f2 line1
f2 line2
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
f2 line18
f2 line19
f2 line20
```

Try doing the same with sed for such a minor change in requirements and note how you're changing the script and it's not portable to other sed versions.